# E6 Pin in Classical Dutch

Tags: opening, dutch-defense

In a classical dutch setup, if white doesn't fianchetto and instead moves bishop c4 then it pins the e6 pawn. I don't really want to go into the stonewall even though that's the recommendation of the engine. Is there any variation or move that can get me out that is NOT the stonewall?

```
[FEN "rnbq1rk1/ppppb1pp/4pn2/5pB1/2BP4/4PN2/PPP2PPP/RN1Q1RK1 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Kh8 unpins the pawn, but I'm not sure if it's worth the tempo loss.

Comment: Why do you not want to enter the Stonewall with d5?

Answer (score 2):

The pin of the `e6` pawn doesn't seem important at all in this position.  In fact, it is hard to see what White is trying to accomplish with `Bc4`.

By "going into Stonewall" I guess you mean `.. d5`, and that is certainly tempting, seeing as White will have to lose a tempo just to put his Bishop on another not-great square.  For an alternative, consider `.. Nc6`, getting ready for `b6` and `Bb7` deploying your light-square Bishop beautifully with action on the central squares `d5` and `e4`.  Also, after `.. Nc6` the `d5` idea will never work for White due to `.. Nxd5!` and White's `g5` Bishop is hanging.